# Office 365 & Azure AD

Tags: office-365, azure

We are using SharePoint Online (Plan 1) at the moment and we have not used any AD services before so all the users and licenses have been managed through O365/SPO admin portals.

Now we noticed that there is an option to sign up for Azure AD. We have learned that it should be free because we have a paid plan and we would love to sign up and see what's it about and get familiar with it. Before that we wanted to make sure that if we sign up for it, will it initially make any changes or break anything on our current setup? We do not want to risk breaking anything at the moment (O365/SPO users and licenes etc.).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Azure AD instance is already setup in the background for each Office 365 tenant. Essentially what's meant with Signing Up is getting an Azure account so that you can access to further settings of Azure AD (such as customizing you Office 365 login page).

Comment: Ok so just for the peace of my mind, if we do that sign up process, it will NOT change/break anything and everything will work the same as now? :-)

Comment: @Tenttu It will not affect anything.  Though, this subscription will only include Azure AD, nothing else.  You will have to create another subscription to utilize other services provided by Azure.

Comment: Hi, I want to use AD for Single Sign-On authentication process. So If I am having any plan of Office 365 then I can have Azure subscription along with it?

Comment: Are you looking to setup SSO between your on-prem AD and Office 365 ? This does not require an Azure subscription, you just need to configure SSO (also requires ADFS server etc on prem).